# Injecting service returns exception

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to inject a service to a component and I get the following message

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDemoString' of undefined

As I understand that the service is not being injected.

**Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'

import {DemoService} from './demo.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'gtbe-navbar',
    templateUrl: 'app/navbar.component.html',
    providers: [DemoService]
})
export class Navbar implements OnInit {

 name: string;

 constructor(private _service: DemoService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this._service.getDemoString();
 }
}
```

**Service**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Injectable()
export class DemoService {

 getDemoString() {
    return "demo";
 }
}
```

Comment: What version of Angular 2 are you using? Since the RC is out, it would make sense to work with that (but obviously your imports betray that you don't).

Comment: this is weird. I have a service with almost the same code as you and it works fine. Please try to import the `Inject` class from `angular2/core` in the service and check if it works.

Comment: Eveyrthing looks good to me. Make sure service import path is correct. please mention your Angular version.

Comment: @guicl i tried to use Inject, didn't work as well, my angular version is "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
        "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
        "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12

Comment: Works as expected - see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/adsGFdVlH7B95CEM5sLs?p=preview). I think your installation is somehow borked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully injected my service to the component. I updated the angular version to the RC and it works.
I had some problems to update it with NPM because the npm and node versions, i update those too and it works.
thanks to @Alfons Ingomar.